# How to change an image size in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

There is the image I'm importing :

```
look_1 = pygame.image.load('data\\png\\look1.png').convert_alpha()
```

And what I tried to get its size reduce was this :

```
pygame.transform.scale()
```

But this seems not to be the right way to do it.

Comment: `pygame.transform.scale()` is correct. What arguments did you pass in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to decide if you want to use Use [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) or [`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale). While `pygame.transform.scale` performs a fast scaling with the *nearest* pixel, `pygame.transform.smoothscale` scales a surface smoothly to any size with interpolation of the pixels.
Scaling up a *Surface* with `pygame.transform.scale()` will result in a jagged result. When downscaling you lose information (pixels). In comparison, `pygame.transform.smoothscale` blurs the *Surface*.

[`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) and [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) are used in the same way. They do not scale the input Surface itself. It creates a new surface and does a scaled "blit" to the new surface. The new surface is returned by the return value. They:

1. Creates a new surface (`newSurface`) with size `(width, height)`.
2. Scale and copy `Surface` to `newSurface`.
3. Return `newSurface`.

```py
look_1 = pygame.image.load('data\\png\\look1.png').convert_alpha()
look_1 = pygame.transform.scale(look_1, (new_width, new_height))
```

or

```py
look_1 = pygame.image.load('data\\png\\look1.png').convert_alpha()
look_1 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(look_1, (new_width, new_height))
```

---

See also [Transform scale and zoom surface](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_surface_scale_and_zoom.md#transform-scale-and-zoom-surface)

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ScaleCenter](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ScaleCenter#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

class ScaleSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.original_image = image
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center)
        self.mode = 1
        self.grow = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.grow > 100:
            self.mode = -1
        if self.grow < 1:
            self.mode = 1
        self.grow += 1 * self.mode 

        orig_x, orig_y = self.original_image.get_size()
        size_x = orig_x + round(self.grow)
        size_y = orig_y + round(self.grow)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.original_image, (size_x, size_y))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

sprite = ScaleSprite(window.get_rect().center, pygame.image.load("Banana64.png"))
group = pygame.sprite.Group(sprite)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    group.update()

    window.fill(0)
    group.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 13):

You can either use `pygame.transform.scale` or `smoothscale` and pass the new width and height of the surface or [`pygame.transform.rotozoom`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotozoom) and pass a float that will be multiplied by the current resolution.

```py
import sys
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))

IMAGE = pg.Surface((100, 60))
IMAGE.fill(pg.Color('sienna2'))
pg.draw.circle(IMAGE, pg.Color('royalblue2'), (50, 30), 20)
# New width and height will be (50, 30).
IMAGE_SMALL = pg.transform.scale(IMAGE, (50, 30))
# Rotate by 0 degrees, multiply size by 2.
IMAGE_BIG = pg.transform.rotozoom(IMAGE, 0, 2)


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        screen.fill(pg.Color('gray15'))
        screen.blit(IMAGE, (50, 50))
        screen.blit(IMAGE_SMALL, (50, 155))
        screen.blit(IMAGE_BIG, (50, 230))
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank ! Works just fine ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Import the Image first.
Then we can use [`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale).
This is a fast-scale operation.

```
self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(35,35))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
size = int(input("What is the size?"))
look_1 = pygame.image.load('data\\png\\look1.png')
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500),0,32)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(look_1, (size, size)), (x, y))
    win.update()
```