# how to reduce the size of an image in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

so since my image are too big i want to reduce the size of them but when start my code the
size is the same
does someone know how to fix that ?

```
width_rock = int(820 / 2)
height_rock = int(495 / 2)

rock_sprite = pygame.image.load("rock.png")
pygame.transform.scale(rock_sprite, (width_rock, height_rock))
window.blit(rock_sprite, (x_rock, y_rock))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

So what this will do is it will get the image, then it will rescale it to the `x` and `y` that are selected, and will rescale it.

[Or this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046376/how-to-change-an-image-size-in-pygame)

```
import pygame
filename = 'rock.png'
picture = pygame.image.load(filename)
picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (1280, 720))
# Or do picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (x_rock,y_rock))
#I have not tested this yet.
```

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.transform.scale` function returns a new `Surface` object, if you want to use the new `Surface` then you need to assign it to the variable. Your code should be something like this:

```
import pygame as pg

# ...

width_rock = int(820 / 2)
height_rock = int(495 / 2)

rock_sprite = pg.image.load("rock.png")
rock_sprite = pg.transform.scale(rock_sprite, (width_rock, height_rock))
window.blit(rock_sprite, (x_rock, y_rock))
pg.display.flip()
```

See the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) for more details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).